# EMI Input filter in SMPS

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, emc

While reading some application notes and standards about **EMI Input filters**, and from the fact that:

- Engineers are responsible for ensuring that a circuit can operate properly in the presence of expected levels of EMI and that it does not **generate** excessive amounts of EMI
- Every conductor or circuit is an antenna that is capable of **transmitting** and **receiving** signals

Many questions come to my mind:

1. The first time I have heard the word **EMI Input filter** in switching converters,  I have expected that filter to prevent some electromagnetic waves from interring the SMPS circuit, like the ones generated by different antennas, mobile phones and so on, such that the SMPS work properly in the presence of these EMI. I was surprised that these filters are designed to prevent a noise signal generated by the SMPS circuit to go back to the universal mains. Why we do not talk just about **a noise filtering** ?
2. What about the effect of these electromagnetic waves generated by other equipment, are they filtered or our circuit receives the electromagnetic waves?
3. Since the switching converters are EMI generators (transmitters), the filter will stop the conducted EMI, but what about the radiated EMI, is-it not a problem that should be circumvented ?
4. Power supplies are designed to feed some circuit, and these converters are noise generators. Do we not need another output filter to prevent that noise (EMI!!) to inter the fed circuit ?

Answer (score 3):

1. They are called input filters because they are on the input lines.
2. SMPS are not especially susceptible to external EMI. If you stop the thing radiating, this will almost certainly ensure adequate susceptibility hardening.
3. Radiated emissions are best addressed by minimising current loops in the wiring/PCB traces, and keeping swicthing transitions as slow as possible for reliable operation. If you still have problems with either, you may need to put shielding round it. Basic shielding can be bolted onto your PCB ground plane.
4. Yes, output filters are every bit as important as input filters.

Answer (score 2):

- ad 1.) I am glad you learned a new thing. I am learning all the time.
- ad 2.) They should be. If there is a rule to stop producing EMI, then if all devices are built in such way, then there shall be no EMI. That's why all those certifications exist.
- ad 3.) In a certification test, there are all parameters that may not be exceeded, including RF noise.
- ad 4) Yes of course. In case of using frequency inverters, choppers, ...etc it is always stated that you have to use a shielded cable and to ground the shield in order to prevent propagating noise. If possible, also the EMI filter is present on outputs.

Answer (score 2):

The cables leading to the input of the SMPS can be very long. Stopping it at the SMPS before it gets into the long input line prevents the line from acting as a giant antenna.

Another consideration is that often you are designing the SMPS for a particular load, so you can account for the SMPS noise to make sure your load works properly. But you often don't have a lot of control over other things that are being powered off the same line as the SMPS input, and those things are probably not expecting an SMPS to be disrupting the line that is powering them.

Answer (score -1):

Input filtering is a two-way requirement. it is mostly for out going to meet the conducted emissions spec with a Pi filter using a Common Mode choke. This also helps reduce lightning transients with an MOV added to the Reg input.